# Issues accessing a microphone from Node on Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero-w, node.js, alsa

I am having issues using a microphone in a Node script.

The microphone (a SEEED Array mic) works when running the command line:

```
arecord -D plughw:1 --duration=10 -f cd -vv ~/rectest.wav
```

It does not work, however, when called from a node script:

```
var record = require('node-record-lpcm16');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('test.wav', { encoding: 'binary' });

record.start({
    sampleRate : 48000,
    verbose : true,
    source: 'plughw:1',
    recordProgram: 'arecord'
}).pipe(file);
```

This sample script runs fine on my mac, but not on my Rpi Zero.

On Rpi Zero have no error message, the file created is empty.

I have tried a number of things (including combinations of source - 1/1,1/1,0/0,1/0,0) but I am having a hard time finding a way to debug.

I have a Speaker Bonnet from Adafruit connected to the RPI (but get the same error when disconnecting it).

I am running node 8.9.3 and have built 'node-record-lpcm16' with no errors.

Any ideas what of what I could be doing wrong or ideas on how to further debug?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a small mistake regarding the naming of the device parameter. It's called `device` and not `source`, changing that should hopefully fix your problem.

ref: https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16/blob/13b5297c1c982281cdb0407d715d46581fb2c9f2/index.js#L58-L60

Another possible small problem, which might actually not matter in this case, is that you are passing the `encoding` parameter to `createWriteStream`. This is meant for telling the stream how to convert JavaScript strings into binary data on disks, but the `record` module will emit `Buffer` instances and not strings.

Finally, a small tip is to use the `dsnoop` module in alsa, so that multiple processes can record at the same time. This might not matter to you though.

Final program:

```
const record = require('node-record-lpcm16')
const fs = require('fs')

const file = fs.createWriteStream('test.wav')

record.start({
  sampleRate: 48000,
  verbose: true,
  device: 'dsnoop:1,0',
  recordProgram: 'arecord'
}).pipe(file)
```

Much of my knowledge here comes from writing a Vinyl LP streamer that streams my vinyl records to my Sonos, using a Raspberry PI Zero W. Feel free to check out the source for some inspiration: https://github.com/LinusU/lp-streamer